# After upgrading my Mac to 10.9.2, vim as merging tool broken

Tags: macos, git, vim, vimdiff

I've upgraded my Mac to 10.9.2, and suddenly found that the vim would complain that the

```
--merge
```

option is unknown. But I haven't change my `~/.gitconfig`, where the options exist and always works find until now.

Does this mean I need to upgrade or install something to fix it?

Comment: I've never seen vim with a --merge command line argument. What command do you have in your .gitconfig?

Comment: I don't know which tool added this line at my gitconfig:

cmd = "vimdiff --merge \"$MERGED\" \"$LOCAL\" \"$(if test -f \"$BASE\"; then echo \"$BASE\"; else echo \"$LOCAL\"; fi)\" \"$REMOTE\""

But I remember that I don't modify this file.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I reset the command with:

```
cmd = "vim -f -d -c \"wincmd J\" \"$MERGED\" \"$LOCAL\" \"$BASE\" \"$REMOTE\""
```

Now it works. So this question is solved now. Thanks.